# Any way to tell EF Core about dependencies amongst IEntityTypeConfiguration classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We have various PostGres database contexts (not using code-first), used in different parts of our system.

And we have shared configurators for tables, implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, and these are added into the contexts as needed.

**Shared configurators**

```cs
public class UserConfigurator : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    builder.Property(p => p.Username).HasColumnName("username");
    ...
}

public class AccountDeviceConfigurator : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AccountDevice>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AccountDevice> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(p => p.CreatedByUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedById)
            .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.LegacyId);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Individual service contexts**

```cs
public class DbApiPostgresContext : DbContext
{
    protected virtual void ApplyConfigurations(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AccountDeviceConfigurator());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfigurator());
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem: there are some navigation properties on some of the entities. If the configuration for navigation property entities is not included in the context, Entity Framework Core will happily build the code but fails at runtime with an obscure error.

For example, if I leave the `ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfigurator())` out of the context shown above, it builds happily but then fails at runtime/test time with weird errors because it can't map some properties in the `User` object.

Is there some way to tell Entity Framework Core that this `IEntityTypeConfiguration` depends on that other one over there (or why can't it tell itself, since the navigation properties are defined in those classes!)?

Comment: Do you add all the configurations in the assembly, or do you just add some of them and want to add navigation properties too? Either way, the solution is to use some reflection and to make it easier create an attribute mark those dependencies, and walk them recursively. (This also can be done over the entities but it might be hard to tell what is an entity and what is not.)